# How to print only the largest file in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu, terminal

I would like to know how can i sort a directory and print out to the terminal only the largest file in that specific directory?
This is my directory:

```html
file1 2
file2 3
file3 1
file4 5
file5 2
```

The wanted result is to print "file4" to the terminal

Comment: `ls` takes the `-S` parameter to sort by size, which sorts from largest to smallest. The `head` program shows you only the first few lines of a file. Together, you can use `ls PATHNAME -S | head -1` to sort the directory PATHNAME by size and display only the first entry (largest file). Including `-r` reverses the sort if you want to also obtain the smallest file.

Comment: How does this have *anything* to do with Sublime Text?

Answer (score 3):

For just files in the directory you can use this:

```
ls -Shld * | head -n 1
```

To include directories you can us du:

```
du -a * | sort -n -r | head -n 1
```